# How to sequence elements based on attribute value in XSD

Tags: xsd, attributes, sequence

Given the following XML:

```
<results>  
    <result type="1">pass</result>  
    <result type="2">pass</result>
    <result type="3">pass</result>
</results>
```

How do I create the XSD that forces the "result" elements to be ordered by the value of the "type" attribute?  Also note, I don't necessarily need an ambiguous sort on the "type" attribute.  I currently have them as enum values and I am expecting exactly one of each value in this specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO XSD doesn't supports what you want. You can not express relationship between attributes contained in elements of list